# Converting an HTML Java script to work with ASP.Net C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Good day everyone,

I have been tasked with recreating a page that was originally written in HTML, to aspx.

I have successfully recreated the page and added additional functionality, but the main thing is it's suppose to run a java script once the submit button is hit.

I have the provided java, but don't really understand how to get it to work with my page.
I'm not even sure where to put the java code to begin with. The other examples online I couldn't make sense to what im trying to do. Please help.

[Took a screen shot since it cuts out a lot of my code for some reason.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziRgf.png)

Comment: Java is not Javascript. Updated the tags.

Comment: You can not put java code on HTML.

Comment: Sorry I am not well versed in Java/Javascript at all. I was told the page is made in HTML and they use this Javascript to process the form, I don't know how they did it, but I'm trying to incorporate this into my aspx page, I just have no idea how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the submit button to a event and run the code inside the script in it.

Something similar to this:

```
$("#[YOUR_SUBMIT_ID_BUTTON]").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //Your JavaScript Code
});
```

Comment: Where do I put this? in the aspx page? or the code behind?

Comment: You referring to the aspx.cs page correct? I don't have a <script> tag anywhere on this page.

Comment: I tried this, I added the section you suggested to my second line of my javascripts. Not sure if it makes sense as there are multiple script tags.

<script>($("#BTN").on('click', function (w, d, s, l, i) { w[l] = w[l] || []; w[l].push({ 'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js' }); var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], j = d.createElement(s), dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : ''; j.async = true; j.src = '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl; f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f); })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-KLPQ37K'));</script>